# How to apply moving windows to a 2D matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, function

I'm doing feature extraction from an image in Matlab. 
I'm having to apply many functions over nXn windows for this purpose (such as to find the variance over each 3X3 window, etc.
Is there an easy and efficient way to do this in Matlab other than looping over the matrix and collecting the window elements each time?
For some functions, I've been able to find an equivalent mask and applied them using filter2, but for many others I don't seem to have such a luxury (one good example: median of a 3X3 window).
What I want is something *like* arrayfun, but something that applies to nXn windows, not individual elements.
Thanks,
Sundar

Comment: It may help if you could update the question and list the specific operations you are wanting to apply to the windowed elements. There may be ways to turn them all into masks/filter elements for use with FILTER2 (or possibly CONV2).

Comment: do you have the image processing toolbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the image processing toolbox then you can use *blkproc* to process *nxm* blocks of your image using custom defined functions. Here is an example

```
function Ip = imageProcessed(II,blockSize)
   % FUNCTION imageProcessed calculates average value of blocks of size nxm
   % blocks 
      if nargin<2,
         % default/example value for block size
         blockSize = [3 4];
      end

      if size(II,3)>1,
          % blkproc requires a grayscale image
          % convert II to gray scale if it is RGB.
          II=rgb2gray(II)
      end


      % Custom average function.
      myAveFun = @(x) ones(size(x))*sum(x(:))/length(x(:));

      % use blkproc to process image
      Ip = blkproc(II,[blockSize(1), blockSize(2)],myAveFun);
end
```

**Note:**

As of MATLAB  2009b's Image Processing Toolbox, *blkproc* was depcrecated and replaced with  *blockproc* (see R2099b section [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/release-notes.html)). So the last two lines could be changed to:

```
 myAveFun = @(blkstrct) ones(size(blkstrct.data))*mean(blkstrct.data(:))
 Ip = blockproc(II,blockSize,myAveFun);
```

Comment: Thank you, I do have the Image processing toolbox and that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: The help for this function pointed me to 'colfilt'. Turns out colfilt with a 'sliding' window makes my job even easier. Thanks for opening up this new array of functions to me.

Comment: Nice catch, Azim. I totally forgot about BLKPROC.

Comment: blkproc has been replaced by blockproc. Could you update your answer to use blockproc?

Comment: @Evan I hadn't realized blkproc was depricated in 2009b. Thanks for the heads up.