# Variograms on Images - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am working on applying geostatistics on Landsat imagery. My focus is on applications of variograms. I will be using n x n windows for generation of variogram plots and texture layers. From an earlier question on stackoverflow [How to apply moving windows to a 2D matrix in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681864/how-to-apply-moving-windows-to-a-2d-matrix-in-matlab), I understood that with Image Processing Toolbox it would be wiser and faster to use functions like blkproc, nlfilter, colfilt etc. instead of normal `for` loop based moving windows.

I see from the help as well as earlier answer that I can integrate other functions to above said functions. But as I have to calculate directional variograms - in EW, NS, NE-SW and NW-SE directions I will have to consider only few pixels(cells of matrix) in front of the central pixel and not all surrounding pixels as in the case of filters. Can anyone suggest how I can go about/or are there functions available to do such operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select a subset of rows and columns in your matrix and pass that in as your matrix variable instead of the entire image.  For example, if your image is `A` and you want rows 2-4 and columns 1-2, use `A(2:4,1:2)`, so `nlfilter`, for example, could be `B = nlfilter(A(2:4,1:2),[m n],fun)`